# Which file format I have to use which supports appending?

Tags: amazon-s3, avro, amazon-athena, orc

Currently We use [orc file format](https://orc.apache.org/) to store the incoming traffic in s3 for fraud detection analysis

We did choose orc file format for following reasons

- compression
- and ability to query the data using athena

Problem :

- As the orc files are read only as soon and we want to update the file contents constantly every 20 minutes
  which implies we

  - need to download the orc files from s3,
  - read the file
  - write to the end of file
  - and finally upload it back to s3

This was not a problem but as the data grows significantly every day `~2GB every day`. It is highly costly process to download 10Gb files read it and write and upload it

**Question :
Is there any way to use another file format which also offers appends/inserts and can be used by athena to query?**

From this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/big-data-file-formats-explained-dfaabe9e8b33) it says `avro` is file format, but not sure

- If athena can be used for querying ?
- any other issues ?

`Note: My skill on big data technologies is on beginner level`

Comment: You can query Avro files with Athena - can't you just upload a new ORC file every day? Athena uses a cluster to read the files and if the data is spread out across multiple objects, it can be easier parallelized.

Comment: Aha thanks will look into it , but due to our platform requirements we need to query the data which is not older than 20 minutes

Comment: More specific requirements would be helpful, otherwise I recommend you get yourself Kinesis Firehose and configure it to batch incoming data up to size `x` or for a maximum of `y` minutes and then store it in S3. Kinesis Firehose can do that in parquet and ORC, both of which can be queried via Athena - [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/record-format-conversion.html)

Comment: Even if file format allows appending (eg you can append to a CSV file), object storage like S3 does _not_ allow appending. If it did, you could see partial data _while_ someone is appending more rows. The recommended approach is to do micro batching on incoming data (as Maurice suggested). If the files are small, they will be expensive to query, so you may need to re-batch them into bigger ones. You can also get more advice from [Trino (formerly Presto SQL) community](https://trino.io/slack.html).

Comment: Looked in to kinesis , but it was way too expensive for ingesting lots of records , any how thanks for the info

Comment: @Maurice currently the requirements are data need to be stored in a way which is really cheaper than current one and query results need not be real time, an accepted delay of 2 hours is acceptable

Comment: 2GB every day, to me, doesn't warrant big data technology. What does the data look like? What is the issue with a proper log indexer like Elasticsearch/Graylog/Splunk?

Comment: @OneCricketeer that is the compressed orc file ,  it is just transactional data and user information, like,ip addresses, products, website links , etc

Comment: Sure, that's how you store the data, but the source doesn't create orc, so you should be able to modify the collection process to upload to systems other than S3

Answer (score 2):

If your table is **not partitioned**, can simply copy (`aws s3 cp`) your new orc files to the target s3 path for the table and they will be available instantly for querying via Athena.

If your table is **partitioned**, you can copy new files to the paths corresponding to your specific partitions. At the end of copying new files to the partition, you need to add or update that partition into Athena's metastore.

For example, if your table is partitioned by `date`, then you need to run this query to ensure your partition gets added/updated:

```
alter table dataset.tablename add if not exists
   partition (date = YYYYMMDD) 
   location 's3://your-bucket/path_to_table/date=YYYYMMDD/'
```